Freezing of the graphics server when waking up from RAM
I have a problem with the graphics server freezing when waking up from RAM.  It does it once every few weeks for a few days, and more often when it wakes up without the power adapter connected.
When I open it up it wakes up but stays black screen (lights off), at certain intervals the black screen flashes with the mouse cursor. I can log in via SSH.  When I try to restart SDDM, it freezes completely.  When I try to shut down via terminal, SSH disconnects and can no longer connect.
It's an Ideapad with AMD, running Kubuntu 23.10.  (It did it in older versions too.)
lshw and dmesg: https://pastebin.com/ksVBaRxb
Thanks for the ideas

The first thing I would check is to make sure your BIOS firmware is up-to-date.  Also, at least on some Lenovo laptops, there is an option between S0iX and S3 suspend in the BIOS setup, though I forget what exactly Lenovo calls the setting.
